# String of SQL doesn't understand in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, mybatis

everybody.
I am making a toy webapp. It uses Spring Boot and Mybatis.
Mybatis mapper configures Java Interface. I expect the string of SQL understands in Intellij. But It doesn't it.

[image]

I expect a like below. If it understands SQL in IntelliJ I have a benefit for work.

[image]

I want to know How to set for it. or no way?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate this feature with the following steps:

1. On you `query` press **Alt + Enter** keys and choose the option: **Inject language or reference**:

[image]

2. Select the most appropiet syntax for you, for example: **SQL (SQL Files)**

[image]

3. Results:

[image]

*For disable that feature, you should press **Alt + Enter** keys on your `query` and choose **Un-inject Language/Reference***

Answer (score 1):

In java file type, use [Inject Language](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-language-injections.html?search=inject#inject_language_command_example) intention action to inject appropriate SQL dialect:
[image: MySQL language injected into String]