# How do you mark a string in Intellij as JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, jpql

This is mostly an organization and styling gripe. I have compile time constant strings in another class that I specify as the queries to an entities `@NamedQueries`, but they do not get highlighted in intellij as JPQL. Is there a way to mark the string as JPQL for intellij to highlight via attributes?

On a related note, is there a more organized place I can put styled JPQL named queries so they do not occupy a huge portion of my entity source files?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382743/string-of-sql-doesnt-understand-in-intellij/43395402#43395402